# Pymongo find query using array index failed as key can be string only

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I'm trying to find all documents with "comment" string in 
"COMMENT" field from documents that look something like this

```py
{
    "_id": "5d10aaf8130d5f9e386be977",
    "info": {
        "files": ["filename"],
        "bands": [{
            "metadata": {
                "": {
                    "COMMENT": "comment"
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "file": "filename"
}
```

I tried this query and everything seemed to work just fine

```py
    comment = coll.find(
        {"info":
            {"bands":
                {"$elemMatch": 
                    { "0":
                        {"metadata":
                            {"":
                                {"COMMENT":
                                    {
                                    "comment"   
                                    }
                                }
                            }    
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

If I try to look at cursor spec I see "set" atribute in it, though I have no idea why.

```py
    > _Cursor__spec:{'info': {'bands': {...}}} 'info':{'bands': {'$elemMatch': {...}}} 'bands':{'$elemMatch': {'0': {...}}}
    > '$elemMatch':{'0': {'metadata': {...}}} '0':{'metadata': {'': {...}}}
    > 'metadata':{'': {'COMMENT': set([...])}} '':{'COMMENT':
    > set(['comment'])} 'COMMENT':set(['comment'])
    > 63587936:'comment'
```

Finally if I try to do

```py
    while (comment.next()):
        print(anything)
```

I get following error:

> bson.errors.InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: set(['comment']),
>   of type:

If I change following part of query

```
{"$elemMatch": { "0":
```

to

```
{"$elemMatch": { 0:
```

or even just

```
{ 0:
```

The error changes to (cursor remains with "set" atribute):

> bson.errors.InvalidDocument: documents must have only string keys, key
>   was 0

P.S.: I tried other queries that didn't include arrays or complicated nesting without any problem

Comment: Your search contains "comment]" (with ']'). Is it a mistake?

Comment: Yes, I did a typo when writing it on Stack, I'll fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I needed to ignore the array index whatsoever and use different syntax to achieve the result

```py
    comment = coll.find({"info.bands.metadata."".COMMENT":"comment"})
```